# reactjs this.props.history.goback not working on android webview

Tags: reactjs

this.props.history.goback not working on android webview. My code is as follows:

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <div className="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/hello">Hello</Link></li>
                        <br />
                        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                        <br />
                        <li><Link to="/books">Books</Link></li>
                        <br />
                    </ul>
                    <hr/>
                    {/* Routes will go here */}
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route path="/books" component={Books} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

class About extends Component{
    goBack = (props) => {
        alert(this.props.history.location.pathname)

        this.props.history.goBack();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <h1 className="display-3">About Me</h1>
                <button onClick={this.goBack.bind(this)}>React Back</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

when i try to go back from my 'About' page, it does not work. same problem with other pages like Hello, Books.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1.You just need to have a module which exports history object. Then you can use it in your anywhere project

    // history.js
    import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

    export default createBrowserHistory({
    /* pass a configuration object here if needed */
    })

    //App component    
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Router history={history}>
              <div className="App">
                  <div className="container">
                      <ul>
                          <li><Link to="/hello">Hello</Link></li>
                          <br />
                          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                          <br />
                          <li><Link to="/books">Books</Link></li>
                          <br />
                      </ul>
                      <hr/>
                      {/* Routes will go here */}
                      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
                      <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
                      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                      <Route path="/books" component={Books} />
                  </div>
              </div>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }

    // some-other-file.js
    import history from './history'
    history.push('/about')
```

or

2.Use context API

```
    class About extends Component {
      static contextTypes = {
         router: () => true, // replace with PropTypes.object if you use them
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <button
            className="button icon-left"
            onClick={this.context.router.history.goBack}>
           Back
          </button>
        )
      }
    }
```

or

3.Use WithRouter HigherOrder component

```
   import React from "react";
   import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

   class Home extends React.Component {
     ...
     myFunction() {
      this.props.history.goBack;
     }
     ...
    }
    export default withRouter(Home);
```